# Rails Forem Engine routes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to mount Forem in my rails application. I added it to my Gemfile and installed it properly. However, whenever I try and load a page under Forem's control (such as "/forums"), I get `NoMethodError`'s on the links with non-Forem routes. These links are in a partial header included in my `application.html.erb`, called `_header.html.erb`:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="nav-wrapper">
    <%= link_to raw("<div>Home</div>"), :root %>
    <%= link_to raw("<div>Forums</div>"), :forem %>
    <%= link_to raw("<div>Events</div>"), :events %>
    <%= link_to raw("<div>Applications <b class='carat'>▼</b></div>"), "#"%> 
    <%= link_to raw("<div>Reports <b class='carat'>▼</b></div>"), "#"%> 
    <%= link_to raw("<div>Tutorials</div>"), "#"%>
    <%= link_to raw("<div>Rules</div>"), '#'%>
    <%= link_to raw("<div>Roster</div>"), :roster %>
    <%= link_to raw("<div>Donations</div>"), '#'%>
    <%= link_to raw("<div>Media Center <b class='carat'>▼</b></div>"), '#'%> 
    <%= link_to raw("<div>L.O.A</div>"), '#'%>
</div>
```

`routes.rb`:

```
mount Forem::Engine, :at => '/forums'  
resources :events
resources :news
devise_for :users
get 'roster' => "users#roster"
get 'news' => "news#index"
get 'profile/:user' => "users#profile", :as => :user_path
root 'news#index'
```

The error:

> NoMethodError in Forem::Forums#index
>
> undefined method `forem_path' for #<#:0x000000031583c8>

And so on for all the other links:

> NoMethodError in Forem::Forums#index
>
> undefined method `events_path' for #<#:0x000000031583c8>
>
> NoMethodError in Forem::Forums#index
>
> undefined method `roster_path' for #<#:0x000000031583c8>

This has to do something with the `routes.rb`'s scope, but I'm not sure how I can get these links working again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have not used Forem but I had this same issue with Monologue.  I think it will help if the links in your header specify that they are part of the main_app.  Example:

Original link to root path might have been:

```
root_path
```

and now should be:

```
main_app.root_path
```

The reason for this is that the Forem Rails engine is a separate Rails application and the links without the prefix only work within the current Rails app (the main app, in this case).

Comment: And note, I'm not sure what the syntax should look like in using :root instead of root_path.  But my example above should work if you change it to root_path (and so on for the rest of the paths) and then put main_app. in front of each.